# Div not applying for all time in the foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

**Here is my entire code for file upload**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/master/js/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
@foreach($value as $val)
<div id="mulitplefileuploader">Upload</div>  // don't confuse with foreach loop it's laravel way
@endforeach  // the loop will run for 5 times (say)
<div id="status"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
var settings = {
    url: "upload.php",
    method: "POST",
    allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip",
    fileName: "myfile",
    multiple: true,
    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
    {
        $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is success</font>");
    },
    onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
    {       
        $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
    }
}
$("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

});
</script>
```

When i try to use  `<div id="mulitplefileuploader">Upload</div>` this in the foreach loop (nearly 5 times ) it appear only at the last loop.

**How can i make it appear on all the loop ?**

### Update :

For better understanding i have created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/L08p1upt/

How can i have a 3 upload option here ?

While i try , i give me like this http://jsfiddle.net/L08p1upt/1/

How can i have three uploads at the same time ?

Here is the [Tutorial](http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/jquery-multiple-file-upload/index.php) i followed

Comment: cool, i am not showing the foreach loop in the code. But i tried with. Let me update the code with that too

Comment: You mean the <div id="mulitplefileuploader">Upload</div> appear more than one time?

Comment: Yes it should (Whether i should use `<div id="mulitplefileuploader1">` , `<div id="mulitplefileuploader2">` like that and get or what ??

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you should use a class to find the elements.

Try:

```
<div id="mulitplefileuploader" class="fileuploader">
```

and

```
$(".fileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
```

As an aside, it's never a good idea to use the same id in more than one element or you'll see this issue a lot. As has been said in the comments, you should enumerate the ids, i.e. multiplefileuploader1, multiplefileuploader2.